# ERROR create from database, convert PostGIS to MBTiles with ogr2ogr

Tags: postgis, mbtiles, ogr2ogr

I am trying to convert data from my PostGIS database into MBTiles format using ogr2ogr.
Howewer, when i type the command

```
ogr2ogr  -f MBTiles "myfile.mbtiles" PG:"dbname=mybase user=postgres password=postgres host=localhost"
```

I am getting an error message

```
ERROR 1: Cannot find min and max zoom_level

ERROR 1: PROJ: proj_create_from_database: SQLite error on SELECT name, coordinate_system_auth_name, coordinate_system_code, geodetic_crs_auth_name, geodetic_crs_code, conversion_auth_name, conversion_code, area_of_use_auth_name, area_of_use_code, text_definition, deprecated FROM projected_crs WHERE auth_name = ? AND code = ?: no such column: area_of_use_auth_name
```

What am I doing bad?